# Теги с нестандартными именами

Tags: html, css

Чем плохи конструкции вида:

```
<foo></foo>
```

И в css:

```
foo {display: block}
```

Заранее спасибо за развёрнутый ответ.

P.S. Извиняюсь за заголовок, парсер съел.

Comment: ничем не плохи, только это `XML`. Язык строгой разметки, а не `html`.

Comment: В `html` лучше так ни делать (насколько я могу полагать могут быть проблемы с кроссбраузерностью).

Comment: Мне всё-равно как это называется. Главное чтобы семантика была лучше, кода меньще, а всё оформление хранилось в CSS :)
Сам знаю, что могут быть проблемы, но вот нагуглить не могу, вот и решил спросить.

Comment: А чем плох div c классом соответствующим семантике?

Comment: Семантике будет только хуже. А раз семантике будет плохо будет плохо accessibility — как реагировать на такой тег программе воспроизводящей речь?

Comment: >Главное чтобы семантика была лучше

А кто этой семантике клиентскую программу обучать будет? Одних стилей для этого недостаточно.

Comment: @ReinRaus, как я понял, вопрос именно в том, зачем использовать атрибут *id* в div'ах, когда можно создать новый тег.

Answer (score 2):

> [Отступление о том, как браузеры обрабатывают неизвестные
>   элементы](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=vZUQ_xPLNDsC&pg=PA71&lpg=PA71&dq=%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BE+%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC,+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B&source=bl&ots=EV3QwS4ekS&sig=Z3jADe2KT9xDOmWUnz0efhSe8eM&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=0Uo6VbOqE4adsAG-rIDgDA&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B&f=false)
>   
> какой стиль по умолчанию должен применяться к неизвестным
>   элементам? 
> Все браузеры отображают неизвестные элементы как
>   встроенные, т.е. так, словно в стилях к ним добавили display: inline.

Comment: это не мои проблемы ))) это проблемы админов сайта. Я свой долг выполнил - ответил на вопрос ))) а за актуальностью - слежу не я. Я бы не оставлял не отвеченные вопросы больше месяца.

Comment: @TheDoctor как будто отвечать на старые вопросы - это плохо

Comment: @discipleartem учитывая, что вопрос и ответ на него могут быть интересны не только ТС, но и многим другим в интернете - актуальность вряд ли сильно уменьшилась

Comment: в теории вопрос может быть актуальным, но лучше удалять старые НЕ отвеченные вопросы, так как при возникновении аналогичного могут быть другие спецификации как для вопроса, так и для ответа.